# Undefined function or variable 'estimateFisheyeParameters'

Tags: matlab

I'm running this code for correction of fisheye distortion but got the error. How can I remove this error.

```
   images 
  =imageDatastore(fullfile(toolboxdir('vision'),'visiondata', ...
   'calibration','fishEye'));
   [imagePoints,boardSize] = 
   detectCheckerboardPoints(images.Files);
   squareSize = 29; % millimeters
   worldPoints = 
   generateCheckerboardPoints(boardSize,squareSize);
  I = readimage(images,1);
  imageSize = [size(I,1) size(I,2)];
  params =  estimateFisheyeParameters(imagePoints,worldPoints,imageSize);
```

Error: Undefined function or variable 'estimateFisheyeParameters'.

Comment: The error message is clear: you don’t have that function that you’re trying to call. I don’t know what you’re hoping to get here.

Comment: Do you have the _Computer Vision System Toolbox_ installed on your system? I guess the `estimateFisheyeParameters` method comes from there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all estimateFisheyeParameters is Introduced in 2017b Hoping you are using same or above.

It also Requires "Computer Vision System Toolbox"

To check which toolboxes you have already installed you can type ver on Matlab Command window.

For more help:
https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimatefisheyeparameters.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm using matlab2016a. Can I install computer vision system toolbox for this version of MATLAB?

Comment: you can install if you have license for same. But estimateFisheyeParameters is Introduced in 2017b so installing in 2016a will not solve your issue.